# How to create a navigation drawer layout which takes user inputs respectively and performs calculations on the click of a button?

Tags: android, calculator, navigation-drawer

All coding was done in android studio.

I created multiple standalone calculator apk's, but I want to combine them all into one single apk. (Just seems more efficient.)

I want to have a home screen and then 4 sub tabs which can each run individual calculations based on their respective inputs.

I have been watching tons of videos and read through multiple threads on how to create a navigation drawer activity.

Some of the videos and threads brought me to the point where I have interactive drawers. That is as far as I can go.

Where exactly must I write the code to read the user input values as well as perform the required calculation.

So to summarize I want to put each app I created thus far into one application but access each different calculator via a navigation drawer tab.

Comment: https://github.com/JustKiddingBaby/SlideMenuLayout

Comment: Please explain more

Comment: This forum makes no sense...

Comment: sorry for the terse comment but your question is really general? please write a more detailed question with what you've tried(with relevant code if possible) and what you want to achieve. according to the information you provided I commented a relevant library(for sliding menu layout suitable for dense UX like what you've described). https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask